# Eventbrite API create private event

Tags: eventbrite

I'm using Eventbrite API to create events from my application, what I need are private events and I create them with this code:

```
 $event_params = array(
                            'title'         => $event->name,
                            'description'   => $event->description,
                            'start_date'    => $event->start_at,
                            'end_date'      => $event->end_at,
                            'timezone'      => 'Europe/Paris',
                            'privacy'       => '0',
                            'venue_id'      => $venue_id,
                            'organizer_id'  => $organizer_id,
                            'capacity'      => $event->capacity,
                            'currency'      => 'EUR',
                            'locale'        => 'fr_FR',
                            'status'        => $event->status,
                            'custom_header' => '<img src="'.asset($event->placeholder_img).'" width="100%"/>'

    );

    $resp = $this->eb_client->event_new($event_params);
```

so the event is created in Eventbrite but it can be shared via social media: http://prntscr.com/6w0b20 and I don't want this thing, I was wondering if this social sharing could be avoid via Eventbrite API.

Thank you,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in our forum, but I'll leave it here as well.

By setting the 'event.shareable' parameter to False you will be able to shut off this feature via the API.

You can see the request parameters for Event Details (event_new's parity endpoint) here http://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-post-events